# Split with multiple special characters: √(A&B)

Tags: java, regex

I have `√(A&B)=|C|`  equation,

after split, I get this value

```
[√, (, A&B, ),=,|, C,|]
```

how can get value like this

```
[√(, A&B, ),=,|, C,|]
```

This my code,

```
return teks.split(""
            + "((?<=\\ )|(?=\\ ))|"
            + "((?<=\\!)|(?=\\!))|"
            + "((?<=\\√\\()|(?=\\√\\())|"    //this is my problem
            + "((?<=\\√)|(?=\\√))|"          //and this
            + "((?<=\\∛)|(?=\\∛))|"
            + "((?<=\\/)|(?=\\|))"
            + "((?<=\\&)|(?=\\&))"
            + "");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `Matcher.find()` for following regexp:

```
String s = "√(A&B)=|C|";
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("("
  +  "(√\\()"
  + "|(\\))"
  + "|(\\w(\\&\\w)*)"
  + "|(=)"
  + "|(\\|)"
  + ")").matcher(s);

ArrayList<String> r = new ArrayList<>();
while(m.find())
  r.add(m.group(1));

System.out.printf("%s", r.toString());
```

Result:

```
[√(, A&B, ), =, |, C, |]
```

**Upd.**

Or, if any symbol before parenthesis (except of "=") should be counted as one symbol with that "(":

```
String s = "√(A&(B&C))=(|C| & (! D))";

Matcher m = Pattern.compile("("
  +  "[^\\s=]?\\(" // capture opening bracket with modifier (if any)
                   // you can replace it with "[√]?\\(", if only
                   // "√" symbol should go in conjunction with brace
  + "|\\)"         // capture closing bracket
  + "|\\w"         // capture identifiers
  + "|[=!\\&\\|]"  // capture symbols "=", "!", "&" and "|"
  + ")").matcher(s.replaceAll("\\s", ""));

ArrayList<String> r = new ArrayList<>();
while(m.find())
  r.add(m.group(1));

    System.out.printf("%s -> %s\n", s, r.toString().replaceAll(", ", ",")); // ArrayList joins it's elements with ", ", so, removing extra space
```

Result:

```
√(A&(B&C))=(|C| & (! D)) -> [√(,A,&(,B,&,C,),),=,(,|,C,|,&(,!,D,),)]
```